# KDE Plasma traditional bug

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

The already mentioned bug seem to be very persistent, even on Plasma 5.24.7.
Can not rename files on desktop nor type more than 1 letter in start bar. Prompt windows for browser download also doesn't allow me to rename.
So I do restart:
`kbuildsycoca5 && kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell`

With this output:

```
kbuildsycoca5 && kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell
kbuildsycoca5 running...
Omitting both --window and --windowclass arguments is not recommended
(base) stepski@stepski:~$ kf.plasma.quick: Applet preload policy set to 1
qml: PlasmaExtras.ScrollArea is deprecated. Use PlasmaComponents3.ScrollView instead.
Plasma Shell startup completed
Trying to use rootObject before initialization is completed, whilst using setInitializationDelayed. Forcing completion
Entry is not valid "org.kde.kontact.desktop" QSharedPointer(0x56171baa3220)
Entry is not valid "org.kde.kontact.desktop" QSharedPointer(0x56171b8bd180)
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.panel/contents/ui/main.qml:18:1: QML DropArea (parent or ancestor of QQuickLayoutAttached): Binding loop detected for property "minimumWidth"
Cyclic dependency detected between "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Globals.qml" and "file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationHeader.qml"
libkcups: CUPS-Get-Printers last error: 1030 No destinations added.
libkcups: Create-Printer-Subscriptions last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.private.systemtray/contents/ui/ExpandedRepresentation.qml:165:9: QML HiddenItemsView: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
libkcups: 0
libkcups: 0
QFont::setPointSizeF: Point size <= 0 (0.000000), must be greater than 0
QFont::setPointSizeF: Point size <= 0 (0.000000), must be greater than 0
QFont::setPointSizeF: Point size <= 0 (0.000000), must be greater than 0
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
org.kde.klipper: Invalid or non-local url for preview:  QUrl("desktop:/awt-pj-ss23-5gmsUi.mp4")
org.kde.klipper: Invalid or non-local url for preview:  QUrl("desktop:/awt-pj-ss23-5gmsUi.pdf")
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Qt Quick Layouts: Detected recursive rearrange. Aborting after two iterations.
Hspell: can't open /usr/share/hspell/hebrew.wgz.sizes.
kf.sonnet.clients.hspell: HSpellDict::HSpellDict: Init failed
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
kf.kio.core: Invalid URL: QUrl("")
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.taskmanager/contents/ui/Task.qml:370: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QWidget::render: Cannot render with an inactive painter
QFont::setPointSizeF: Point size <= 0 (0.000000), must be greater than 0
qt.gui.imageio.jpeg: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kickoff/contents/ui/ApplicationsPage.qml:116: TypeError: Cannot call method 'forceActiveFocus' of null
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "width"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "width"
QQmlEngine::setContextForObject(): Object already has a QQmlContext
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
QQmlEngine::setContextForObject(): Object already has a QQmlContext
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/kirigami.2/ScrollablePage.qml:200:9: QML MouseArea: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
QQmlEngine::setContextForObject(): Object already has a QQmlContext
Could not find the Plasmoid for Plasma::FrameSvgItem(0x56171a606e10) QQmlContext(0x56171bee11a0) QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Globals.qml")
Could not find the Plasmoid for Plasma::FrameSvgItem(0x56171a606e10) QQmlContext(0x56171bee11a0) QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Globals.qml")
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
Could not find the Plasmoid for Plasma::FrameSvgItem(0x56171b58c7a0) QQmlContext(0x56171bee11a0) QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Globals.qml")
Could not find the Plasmoid for Plasma::FrameSvgItem(0x56171b58c7a0) QQmlContext(0x56171bee11a0) QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Globals.qml")
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
Could not find the Plasmoid for Plasma::FrameSvgItem(0x56171dc40fb0) QQmlContext(0x56171bee11a0) QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Globals.qml")
Could not find the Plasmoid for Plasma::FrameSvgItem(0x56171dc40fb0) QQmlContext(0x56171bee11a0) QUrl("file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/global/Globals.qml")
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/plasma/components.3/ScrollView.qml:45:27: QML ScrollBar: Binding loop detected for property "visible"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/SelectableLabel.qml:38:5: QML TextArea: Binding loop detected for property "implicitHeight"
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationItem.qml:219:21: QML SelectableLabel: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
```

Terminal command is still running.In the mean time I tried to reach Kubuntu forum directly, offer my support to fix this bug - but seems that I don't have permission to post anything as a fresh user.

Comment: Bug reports are offtopic here, but anyway, you haven't linked to the bug report you allude to. Also, no clear what you mean by `I don't have permission to post anything as a fresh user`. The Plasma version you mention is also wrong, I guess you mean 5.24. 7 in Kubuntu 23.04.